# Hide password in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My Jenkinsfile (Declarative Pipeline) content as follows,

```rb
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                git url: 'git@github.com:org/repository.git'
            }
        }
        
        stage('Script') {
            steps {
                sh 'script.sh' 
            }
        }
    }
```

In my `script.sh` i have `username` and `password` in below format

```bash
#!/bin/bash

USERNAME="user"
PASSWD="mypassword-here"
```

Through Declarative pipeline(Jenkinsfile), I'm trying to hide the password which is in my `script.sh` file.

In my jenkins `Global credentials page`, already created kind as `Username with password` then updated my `script.sh` as below

```bash
#!/bin/bash

USERNAME="user"
PASSWD="$MY_CREDS_PSW"
```

But it is not working. Can i know how do i add my `jenkins Global credentials` created as Kind-ID in my script to hide the password?

Comment: have you considered using the credentials manager in Jenkins? and then the [withCredentials](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/) plugin

Comment: `Credentials Binding Plugin` already been installed.

Comment: but your pipeline is not using `withCredentials(...) {...}`

Comment: I have added under the below in my `script` stage.`withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'MY_SCRIPT_CRED', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME')]) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make use of the withCredentials block. Here's an updated version of your Jenkinsfile:

```
    pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                git url: 'git@github.com:org/repository.git'
            }
        }

        stage('Script') {
            steps {
                withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'YOUR_CREDENTIALS_SpeciifcID', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORDD', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME')]) {
                    sh 'script.sh'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, replace 'YOUR_CREDENTIALS_SpecificId' with the actual ID of your Jenkins Global credentials that you created. The withCredentials block allows you to inject the username and password from your Jenkins Global credentials into the environment variables USERNAME and PASSWORDD within the scope of the sh step.

In your script.sh, you van add USERNAME PASSWORD